How to avoid x-axis labels getting cut off in GraphicsGrid?
I have the code below, but the plot labels are obscured by the frame box. Can anybody please help to fix. I tried PlotRangePadding but could not get it to work for the example below. Thanks
tt = 3;
p1 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[A, 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p2 = Plot[3 (1 - E^(-2 t)), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[B, 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p3 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t) - 4 E^(-3 t), {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[C, 18], LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p4 = Plot[3 t E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[D, 18], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p5 = Plot[(3 + 10 t) E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["E", 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3, 3.5}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p6 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t) Sin[2 t], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[F, 18], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2, p3}, {p4, p5, p6}}, Frame -> All]


A simple solution would be to  ImageMargins->10 to each plot.  (Careful with that Style[D,12]. While it works here, D has a special meaning in the WL.)

Add ImagePadding -> 10] to the first plot (p1)
tt = 3;

p1 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[A, 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue], ImagePadding -> 10];
p2 = Plot[3 (1 - E^(-2 t)), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[B, 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p3 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t) - 4 E^(-3 t), {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[C, 18], LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p4 = Plot[3 t E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[D, 18], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p5 = Plot[(3 + 10 t) E^(-2 t), {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["E", 18], 
   Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1, 3, 3.5}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];
p6 = Plot[3 E^(-2 t) Sin[2 t], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> Style[F, 18], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue]];


GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2, p3}, {p4, p5, p6}}, Frame -> All]



I notice that you did not accept the answer to this question. Is there something that remains to be addressed?
